# Leaflet-Realtime plugin with GeoJson and multiple markers

Tags: leaflet, real-time, geojson

Hello guys i am trying to update my markers position but i don't manage to find out how to remove the old ones. All i get is a "history" of the marker. I didnt any examples that will help me. I hope someone will give me a clue to go on.
Many thanks to [Per Liedman](http://www.liedman.net/) for the awesome job.

```
                    var shipLayer = L.layerGroup();
                    var ships = L.icon({
                        iconUrl: '../icons/ship-icon.png',
                        iconSize: [30, 30]
                    });
                    var realtime = L.realtime({
                        url: 'jsonServlet/ships.json',
                        crossOrigin: true,
                        type: 'json'
                    }, {
                        interval: 5 * 1000,
                        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {

                            marker = L.marker(latlng, {icon: ships});
               marker.bindPopup('mmsi: ' + feature.properties.mmsi +
                               '<br/> course:' + feature.properties.hdg+
                               '<br/> speed:' + feature.properties.sog);
                               marker.addTo(shipLayer);
                               return marker;
                        }                            
                    });  
                  controlLayers.addOverlay(geojson, 'Ships');
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your ships.json? As [this bug report](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime/issues/10) explains, "Leaflet Realtime will try to look for a called property id and use that [to remove old markers]". You should try that if you are able to change the json creation process.

Comment: {"type":"FeatureCollection","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}},"features":[{"geometry":{"coordinates":[48.517708,18.255447],"type":"Point"},"type":"Feature","properties":{"geometry/coordinates/longitude":"48.517708","geometry/type":"Point","mmsi":"512131345","geometry/coordinates/latitude":"18.255447","hdg":"108","cog":"108","sog":"30.0","type":"Feature"}}]}  ID in this json is mmsi (unigue merchant ship code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default L.realtime uses the `id` property of a feature to update it. As you explained in the comments, the identifier of your ships are in the GeoJSON feature's `mmsi` property and there is no `id`. You will need to add this to your L.realtime setup in `options`:

```
getFeatureId: function(featureData){
    return featureData.properties.mmsi;
}
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/chk1/hmyxb6ur/

Comment: Ok. That was the problem. i was not able to combine  both "pointToLayer" and "getFeatureId". You make my weekend my friend. Thanks a lot.